# Virtualbox: Is it possible to get a different public-ip on the guest system from host's public-ip?

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox

i'd like to set my guest's **public**-ip (windows xp) undependent from the host's ip as a different one. Is it possible? If so, how do i do it?

Please note that, it's about the public id, not the local ones..

Thank you very much..

Answer (score 1):

If you set the virtual network card connection to be "Bridged" rather than "NAT" then you can set the IP address in the virtual machine to the same format as the host machine.

Examples (assuming you do the above):

Host: DHCP (e.g., 192.168.1.x)

Virtual: DHCP

Result: Virtual will have a 192.168.1.x address

Host: Manually set (e.g., 10.1.1.1)

Virtual: Manually set (10.1.1.2)

Result: host can connect to virtual via 10.1.1.2

End result is that any machine on the network would be able to connect to the virtual machine via its own IP address and you wouldn't need to configure anything to map across to it

Hope this helps

Dave

Comment: Hi, but i want to change my **public** -ip not the local one. I still got the same public ip adress after that changes...

Comment: Once you configure the virtual network card as "bridged", you can think of it as another physical machine on your network. Therefore, whatever you did to expose the public IP address of the host machine would need to be done for the virtual machine also I would imagine.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, in a home environment, no matter the operating-system or virtualization.

The issue is: both (or all machines) on this home-network are leaving through the router to access the internet. The router is the one machine, that actually has the public ip, everything else is available through translated addresses (NAT).

There would be at least two ways to achieve the wanted situation:

1. Use a VPN on one of the machines, so it "leaves" the internal network at another place.
2. Get a second internet-line, and assign the router of this line as the gateway for the other machine.

Answer (score 0):

although this isn't a current post, are you trying to change what address the website/person sees you as?
if so, just use a web proxy or download your own, other than that you can use a private secure network.
Though these aren't fool proof, you can use them to, for example let a US website think you're from Russia or visa versa.

This all comes from programs you install on the virtual machine after using the above method to give the VM its own ip address. (although you could do it for host only and not bridge adapter if you felt like it)

Comment: I don't think downloading the proxy and using it would change their web-facing IP though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a VPN on one of the machines, so it "leaves" the internal network at another place.
I think this can help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).